# consejos con estas lineas

Tags: javascript, java, javadoc

tengo una duda muy grande, y es que me pidieron desarrollar este ejercicio que la verdad no he podido desarrollarlo de buena forma, y lo que alcanze a desarrollar estoy seguro que esta algo mal o varias cosas mal ya que me da algunos errores, y como soy novato me cuesta entenderlos, me puede ir guiando en lo que estoy mal o que me falta?
el ejercicio es Desarrolla una clase Canción con los siguientes atributos:

titulo: una variable String que guarda el título de la canción.

autor: una variable String que guarda el autor de la canción.

y los siguientes métodos:

Cancion(String, String): constructor que recibe como parámetros el título y el

autor de la canción (por este orden).

Cancion(): constructor predeterminado que inicializa el título y el autor a cadenas

vacías.

dameTitulo(): devuelve el título de la canción.

dameAutor(): devuelve el autor de la canción.

ponTitulo(String): establece el título de la canción.

ponAutor(String): establece el autor de la canción.

y lo que yo he hecho hasta e momemento es ;

```
public class Cancion {
private String titulo;
private String autor;

public Cancion(String titulo,String autor){
this.titulo=titulo;
this.autor=autor;
}

public String getTitulo (){
return titulo;
 }
public void setTitulo(String titulo){
 this.titulo=titulo;
}

public String getAutor(){
return autor;
 }

public void setAutor(String autor){
this.autor = autor;
 } 

public String dameTitulo(){
  return titulo;
}

public String dameAutor(){
 return autor;
}

 public String ponTitulo(String ponTitulo){

 return titulo;

 }



 @Override
public String toString(){
return "el titulo de la cancion es " + titulo + " y el autor es "+ autor;
}


}
```

y en otra lado tengo la clase main la verdad no he podido terminar el ejercicio no se como proseguir, quisiera pedir la ayuda de que me puedan guiar porfavor

mi main es
public class NewMainejercicio6 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cancion Cancion1 = new Cancion("Dont cry","Guns and roses");
    String tituloo;
    String autor;
   
    System.out.println(Cancion1);
    
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("ingresa el titulo de una cancion");
    tituloo = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.println ("ingresa el autor");
    autor = entrada.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("El titulo de la cancion es "+ tituloo + " y el autor es "+ autor);
}
```

}

Comment: va bien hasta `dameAutor`. `ponTitulo` y `ponAutor` deberían hacer lo mismo que `setTitulo` y `setAutor` respectivamente

Comment: deberia borrarls?o escribir el mismo codigo de settitulo y set autor? disculpa cual seria la diferencia? es que aun estoy unpoco confundido

Comment: lo que dice el primero comentario es verdad, deberías hacer que dame titulo y dame autor hagan lo mismo que tus 2 set. en realidad yo reemplazaría el nombre de los 2 set por los 2 nombres finales y ya. Solo porque te piden esos nombres y en tu constructor debs inicializar ambos parametros con un valor por defecto en vacio. tienes el constructor con los parametros solo crea otro constructor sin parametros e inicializas allí en vacío los datos o en la creacion de las variables creas ambos inicializados en vacío.

Comment: Tu post está mal formulado, no tiene ninguna pregunta. Qué es lo que quieres?

Comment: En la respuesta de arriba te hacen unas correcciones sobre 2 métodos en los que tu lógica no es la correcta, por otro lado lo que tendría para decirte es que trates de no mezclar inglés con español dentro de tu código y conservar la indentación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque tu "pregunta" está mal formulada voy a intentar responderla.
Supongo que lo que intentas hacer es esto

```
public class Cancion {
    private String titulo;
    private String autor;

    public Cancion(String titulo, String autor) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public String dameTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void ponTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String dameAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public void ponAutor(String autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "el titulo de la cancion es " + titulo + " y el autor es " + autor;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("ingresa el titulo de una cancion");
    String titulo = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.println ("ingresa el autor");
    String autor = entrada.nextLine();
    Cancion cancion = new Cancion(titulo, autor);
    System.out.println(cancion.toString());
}
```

Comment: Gracias, la verdad me aclaraste muchas dudas que tenia, pensaba que el usuario debia ingresar por teclado el nombre de la cancion, muchas gracias

Comment: Si te sirvio marcalo como respuesta